# Is there any way to view a youtube live stream WITHOUT being on youtube?

Tags: youtube

I am on my school PC and tried to watch a stream. It didnt work because it was restricted. I tested this with different ones and they were all resricted.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out of your school account. You can also look for things in the YouTube API, or embed the youtube video in another site.